# Degrading a jpg image quality each time a user visits a page?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying to work out the best way to degrade the quality of a jpeg image in a web page like this http://vimeo.com/3750507

Is there a server-side way of saving and re-saving at a lower quality then displaying an image each time the page is served?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. GD or ImageMagick. PHP supports both.

Comment: Presumably you will need to use cookies if you are doing it on a per-user basis, so you could increment the number of visits in a cookie and use that to calculate a JPEG quality factor.

Comment: GD is on by default, ImageMagick may not be installed on your host. For that specific problem, you should go with GD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script will degrade the original image by 1 'quality point' on each page load, starting at 99. This isn't very robust, but should clearly demonstrate the concept.

***Warning: this will replace the original image! Use a copy if the original is important!***

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['quality'])) $_SESSION['quality'] = 99;

$file = 'degrade.jpg';

imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($file), $file, $_SESSION['quality']);

$_SESSION['quality']--;

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

On first page load:

[image: first run]

Tenth page load:

[image: tenth run]

One hundredth page load:

[image: one hundredth run]